# Difference between 決して~ない 絶対~ない 全く~ない 全然~ない

Tags: grammar, word-choice

They all need to make a negative sentence but I can't understand the differences between them

Comment: 'They all need to make a negative sentence' ｰｰ but you can also say 「全くその通りです」とか「絶対行きます」

Answer (score 2):

決して~ない and 絶対~ない talk about the confidence level (I am very confident that there is no x). Whereas 全く~ない and 全然~ない talk about the degree (there is no level of x).

Between 決して and 絶対, the latter is a bit colloquial. Otherwise there is little difference. 決して might be used more frequently when addressing a suspicion.

Between 全く and 全然, the latter is again a bit colloquial but to a lesser degree compared to 絶対~ない. Both mean very similar things and I'd be hard pressed to come up with a difference.